# How can I get the account ID number programmatically with Aliyun Python SDK?

Tags: python-3.x, alibaba-cloud

I need to programmatically get the account ID number, in a way that does not depend on a local config file with info about local account configuration. I want to automate reports and need the ID number as a data point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of such an API to return only the account ID. But some APIs do return the account ID along with other information, e.g. this [GetRole](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/28711.htm) API. The account ID is part of the `<Arn>acs:ram::123456789012****:role/ECSAdmin</Arn>` so you can parse out the account ID.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is an English language version of this page?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the account ID from the STS API:
https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/doc-detail/43767.htm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).